# InstanceAlreadyExistsException for EnvironmentManager when trying to start Spring Boot application in plain Spring test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

I have simple web application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
   }
}

@RestController
public class SimpleController {

   @Autowired
   private String sayHello;

   @GetMapping("/hello")
   public String hello() {
       return sayHello;
   }
}

@Configuration
public class StringConfig {
   @Bean
   public String sayHelloWorld() {
      return "Hello, World!";
   }
}
```

And add tests:

```
 //This is abstarct class for test.
 @WebAppConfiguration
 @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
 @ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
 public abstract class AbstractTestClass {

     @Autowired
     private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

     protected MockMvc mockMvc;

     @Before
     public void init() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    }
 }

 //This is custom configuration for bean "sayHello".
 @Configuration
 public class ConfigurationForTest {
    @Bean
    public String sayHello() {
       return "Hello, Test1!";
    }
 }

 //This test loads custom config with ApplicationContext.
 @ContextConfiguration(classes = ConfigurationForTest.class)
 public class SimpleControllerTest1 extends AbstractTestClass {

    //Checks that enpoind return expected reponse.
    @Test
    public void shouldReturnHelloTest1() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/hello"))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().string("Hello, Test1!"));
   }
}

//This test don't loads custom configuration and works on default ApplicationContext.
public class SimpleControllerTest2 extends AbstractTestClass {

   //Checks that enpoind return expected reponse.
   @Test
   public void shouldReturnHelloWorld() throws Exception {
      mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/hello"))
             .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content()
                                             .string("Hello,World!"));
   }
}
```

This test fails with:

`Failed to load ApplicationContext
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext`

`Caused by: org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.environment.EnvironmentManager@1ed864e4] with key 'environmentManager'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.cloud.context.environment:name=environmentManager,type=EnvironmentManager`

`Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.cloud.context.environment:name=environmentManager,type=EnvironmentManager`

What is it caused by? It isn't clear for me. I know that i can add `@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)`or use other annotation `@WebMvcTest`, `@SpringBootTest + @AutoConfigureMockMvc`. 
But I want to know why is it happend and and how to load the whole application context dirrectly using this approach if my application will be more complex?

What is the difference between `@ContextConfiguration(classes=Application.class)` and `@SpringBootTest`. Why does this error not occur when i use `@SpringBootTest`? With  `@SpringBootTest` ApplciationContext is loaded twice too, but tests pass successfully.

Comment: I have the impression that your question is for a very specific case. This is okay, but when you ask these kind of questions, it is important that you provide a good summary with the necessary level of detail. Otherwise, people may think that the question matches their problem, spend time reading through it, and eventually are disappointed (and express this through down-votes...)

Comment: @oberlies, Thank you for these remark.